# Sorting highscore by time and number of guesses

Tags: java

As of now my highscore list is only sorted by number of guesses. I would like entries with identical number of guesses to also be sorted by time in ms, in descending order. Tried searching and found some similar Q's but couldn't really find a solution. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated! Feel free to comment on other parts of my code as well!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

private static ArrayList<highScore> score = new ArrayList<highScore>();

private class highScore implements Comparable<highScore> {

    int guessCount = 0;
    double playerTime = 0;
    String playerName;

    public highScore (int guessCount, double playerTime, String playerName) {
        this.guessCount = guessCount;
        this.playerTime = playerTime;
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String scoreList = (this.playerName + "\t\t" + this.guessCount + "\t\t" + this.playerTime);
        return scoreList;
    }

    public int compareTo(highScore hs) {
        if (((Integer)this.guessCount).compareTo(((Integer)hs.guessCount)) > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    boolean playGame = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Game g = new Game();

    while(playGame) {
        g.start();

        System.out.println("\nPlay again?");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.print("Quitting...");
                playGame = false;
        }
    }
}

public void start() {

    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1001 );
    int guess = -1;
    int guessCount = 0;
    String guessStr, playerName;
    String quit = "quit";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean play = true;

        System.out.print("Welcome to the greatest guessing game of all time!" + 
        "\nGuess a number between 1-1000!" + 
        "\nType \"quit\" to quit.");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("\nDEBUG, nr is: " + number);

        while (guess != number && play) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
                guessStr = scan.nextLine();
                    if (guessStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                        play = false;
                        System.out.println("Quitting...");
                        return;
                }
                guess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);

                if (guess <= 1 || guess > 1000) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid guess, won't count, try again!");
                }
                if (guess < number) {
                    System.out.println("Too low, try again!");
                    guessCount++;
                }
                if (guess > number) {
                    System.out.println("Too high, try again!");
                    guessCount++;
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, only numbers. Try again!");
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ex) {             
                System.out.println("Sorry, only numbers. Try again!");
            }
        }

        if (guess == number) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long gameTime = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Nice, the correct number is " + number + "!");
            System.out.print("You nailed it after " + (int)(gameTime)/1000 + " seconds and " + guessCount + " tries!");
            System.out.println("\nEnter your name!");

            playerName = scan.nextLine();
            score.add(new highScore(guessCount, gameTime, playerName));
            Collections.sort(score);

            System.out.println("Name ------- Guesses -------- Time in ms");
            for (highScore h: score) {
                System.out.println(h);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: `compareTo` is really bad you need to only do `return Integer.valueOf(this.guessCount).compareTo(hs.guessCount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compareTo() method of highScore has to be implemented as below

```
public int compareTo(highScore hs)
{
    if (((Integer)this.guessCount).compareTo(((Integer)hs.guessCount)) > 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        if(this.guessCount == hs.guessCount)
        {
          if(this.playerTime > hs.playerTime)
          {
             return 1;
          }
          else
          {
             return -1;
          }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify your `compareTo` method to consider the equality case also. And then move to the next comparison: -

```
public int compareTo(highScore hs) {

    if (this.guessCount == hs.guessCount) {
         return (new BigDecimal(this.playerTime)).compareTo(
                 new BigDecimal(hs.playerTime)
    } else {
         return Integer.valueOf(this.guessCount).compareTo(
                Integer.valueOf(hs.guessCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmitD. Well, thanks. All credit to 250 Bounty that I got today only. But what's wrong with the answer?

Comment: You can just use in if `Integer.valueOf(this.playerTime ).compareTo(hs.playerTime )` and in else `Double.valueOf(this.guessCount).compareTo(hs.guessCount)` compareTo should also support equality case so this will be handled by that other wise your function never returns `0` which means if suppose equals is written then on these terms two objects are equal then their compareTo will never return `0` even if they are equal

Comment: @AmitD. No, playerTime is a double type. Thats why I gave an example of `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

**-** Whenever you need to **sort on the basis of more than 1 attributes**, go for `java.util.Comparator` Interface.

**-** Use the `compare()` method of `Comparator<T>` along with `Collections.sort(List l, Comparator c)` to sort you list.